# Where Clauses Causing Errors in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to return rows based on a search term that may include a space.

The code below is is generating the following error. I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong, any suggestions?

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query
>   operators except the Contains operator.

```
var searchTerms = term.Split(' ').ToList();
var surveys = (from s in dc.BasicNeedsSurveys where s.Hidden == 
false orderby s.CreatedOn descending select s)
.Where(x => searchTerms.Any(y => y.Contains(x.FirstName)) 
|| searchTerms.Any(y => y.Contains(x.LastName)) 
|| searchTerms.Any(y => y.Contains(x.FEMANumber)));
```

Comment: The error message is accurately diagnosing the problem; can you clarify your question?

Comment: @eric-lippert, I modified the question. I'm trying to return results using lamda expressing where the search term needs to be tried against various fields for a match.

Comment: Your code *looks* like you're searching for some particular text. I assume `searchTerms` is a set of terms you're searching for. If that's true, your query should actually be `searchTerms.Contains(x.LastName)` rather than `searchTerms.Any(y => y.Contains(x.LastName))`. The latter means if you have the terms `["test", "this"]`, you'll match to someone with the last name `'hi'`, since `this` contains `hi`.

Comment: As a bonus, this fixes your issue since `Contains()` *is* supported, while `Any()` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the error message you are using linq to sql (or EF). linq to sql generate SQL query behind the scene, and you cant use a local var such as searchTerms inside an sql query. if i understand it correctly and  dc.BasicNeedsSurveys is actually a data base entity (like in entity framework for example) your solution will be to first execute the sql query and then run the test if substring of search terms contains the search result. ToList is one function that can do that.

```
var searchTerms = term.Split(' ').ToList();
var surveys = (from s in dc.BasicNeedsSurveys where s.Hidden == 
false orderby s.CreatedOn descending select s)
.ToList()
.Where(x => searchTerms.Any(y => y.Contains(x.FirstName)) 
|| searchTerms.Any(y => y.Contains(x.LastName)) 
|| searchTerms.Any(y => y.Contains(x.FEMANumber)));
```

of course, there might be better ways to do that with better performance since here you are filtering the results only after you read all of them from the hard drive, but there is really not enough information in the question for that

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to perform it all at the database. If @Rob's assumption is correct then you'll end up matching bad data and it'd be preferable to let the db do the query, especially if your dataset is large. The single filter on the hidden field smells of a table that might possibly have many, many records.

Comment: Of course it would be better performance-wize. Only in large organizations many times programmers have no permissions to access the database, in some noSql platforms like RavenDB you CANT run queries directly on the db and generally if the entire application doesnt use SQL for the sake of source control and easy maintenance maybe its better to get lower performance and have this query work the same as everything else. There isnt enough info for such considerations in the quetsion, and the answer specifically says so. That answer is one easy option that fits some situations